# How to make a voice channel with europe regoin - discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How to make a voice channel with europe regoin?
help me, I've tried to do it with `stRETCH Region: ('europe'),` but it doesn't work;

```js
async function jointocreatechannel(user) {
    console.log(" :: " + user.member.user.username + "#" + user.member.user.discriminator + " :: Created a Room")
    await user.guild.channels.create(`${user.member.user.username} ini temp ajg`, {
        type: 'voice',
        parent: user.channel.parent.id,
        setRTCRegion: ('europe'),
    }).then(async vc => {
        user.setChannel(vc);
        jointocreatemap.set(`tempvoicechannel_${vc.guild.id}_${vc.id}`, vc.id);
        await vc.overwritePermissions([
            {
                id: user.id,
                allow: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
            },
            {
                id: user.guild.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
        ]);
    })
}
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? I think `setRTCRegion` is (or will be) available in v13 only.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros discord.js V12.5.3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a little hack here. Since it is not supported natively in discord.js v12. After the channel creation you can perform raw API request, to modify the channel and set the region. For reference see [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#modify-channel).

```js
const channelId = "...";

client.api.channels(channelId).patch({
    data: {
        rtc_region: "europe"
    }
});
```

Note that the `client` is an instance of [`Discord.Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client).

Comment: Well, I tested it, `MANAGE_CHANNELS` permission for the bot should be enough. Could you show me your full code how you are calling it? Is there any error message thrown?